# should I correct for number of models?

Tags: model, lm

I've built about 8 models, each testing slightly different things but within the scope of the same study.

```
group <- rep(c("control","treatment"),each=10)
sub <- rep(c(1:10),times=2)
y1 <- c(23,15,62,12,45,66,24,26,25,24,14,21,23,78,54,34,21,45,77,56)
y2 <- c(33,26,72,56,22,75,84,55,68,22,52,28,62,99,44,39,55,43,44,55)
y3 <- c(24,16,62,62,75,63,28,26,85,25,54,41,27,48,88,53,27,24,56,52)
y4 <- c(76,28,76,55,86,75,28,64,78,45,52,54,73,27,23,53,47,65,74,53)
x1 <- c(61,72,51,73,41,78,45,85,24,74,15,86,32,15,74,21,76,46,74,78)
x2 <- c(55,66,50,66,27,65,24,72,11,43,14,73,27,12,55,11,65,37,54,67)
cov <- c(43,53,63,23,25,54,34,43,33,23,43,36,37,45,56,58,44,32,28,20)

df <- data.frame(sub,group,y1,y2,y3,y4,x1,x2,cov)
```

I expect `x1` and `x2` to be highly correlated, and so I would like to run all these different models

```
m1x1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1 + cov, data=dat)
m2x1 <- lm(y2 ~ x1 + cov, data=dat)
m3x1 <- lm(y3 ~ x1 + cov, data=dat)
m4x1 <- lm(y4 ~ x1 + cov, data=dat) 
m1x2 <- lm(y1 ~ x2 + cov, data=dat)
m2x1 <- lm(y2 ~ x2 + cov, data=dat)
m3x1 <- lm(y3 ~ x2 + cov, data=dat)
m4x2 <- lm(y4 ~ x2 + cov, data=dat)
```

I have a priori hypotheses why these different models should be built, but adjusting for multiple testing seems like overkill, because model effects aren't particularly strong (although some do meet the required significance level).

I am concerned however that reviewers might ask for some kind of adjustment.

So would you correct the p value to account for the number of models?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve (and perhaps, on what your audience will expect). If you chose your significance level based on a careful tradeoff of type I and type II error rates at some fixed sample size, then it would almost certainly be interfering with the original aim to do some adjustment of significance level or p-value for multiple testing. If you have to meet some arbitrary level of overall type I error rate to get a paper published, then certainly you need to do it. In other situations it may be yes or no, but it will depend on the circumstances.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "If you chose your significance level based on a careful tradeoff of type I and type II error rates at some fixed sample size"? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Could you incorporate the additional information into your question, please? It provides useful context for anyone attempting an answer.

Comment: A number of possible situations exist, but here's a nice simple one -- "our total sample size can be no more than 7 across the control and treatment groups so power will be low; we'd like to achieve at least 40% power if the distributions are logistic with scale parameter 1.1 and a shift alternative where the raw effect size is 3.0. We're doing a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test, so the lowest attainable significance level is 0.057143, anyway. If we do set the significance level to that lowest attainable level, we should just attain the desired minimal power at that effect size." ... ctd

Comment: ctd... . If you do two such tests are try to Bonferroni it (for a simple example), you'll never reject either null and your power becomes 0. Considerably more careful tradeoffs are possible where you might consider both specific costs of both kind of error and some sense of the relative chances of the two hypotheses being the case in order to choose a significance level.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, that was very helpful. I never thought about it in this way. It's true that I'm using a fixed sample, so this approach sounds reasonable. But how did you arrive at 40% power and effect size of 3.0, these are arbitrary values right? Are there any guidelines I can base my choices on though? And how did you compute the required significance level based solely on this information? I have 20 subjects in the control and treatment groups and would like to run a series of linear models like in my example above.

Comment: Forget about the multiplicity issue. A more reasonable approach is to totally abandon the conventional framework: https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/706747v1

Comment: @locus Those numbers were arbitrarily chosen for the example. You don't compute a required significance level in general, you're choosing one (though I set the example up so that the minimum achievable level turned out okay for the desired power, so that choice was easy). If you set up an explicit relationship between the two types of error then you may be able to compute one. This is getting into a whole other (much more complex) question than the one you started with though.

Comment: Your posted example appears to list the same model ten times, which obviously is not what you're doing.  How exactly do these models differ?  This matters (a lot) because it affects what kind of principled approaches you can take to obtaining and reporting the results.

Comment: @whuber, the models are predicting different things (y1, y2, y3 ... y10). I edited my question with a minimal example data frame to exemplify what I mean

Comment: @Glen_b, but in your comment you wrote "so the lowest attainable significance level is 0.057143". I take it this was derived from somewhere, or did you also choose this number arbitrarily?
You also wrote "I set the example up so that the minimum achievable level turned out okay for the desired power", but how do I determine the minimum achievable level for a given power? I looked into G*Power (which can compute required alpha based on sample and effect sizes) but I still cannot understand how you arrived at that number...

Comment: Thank you for the modifications: the nature of your question looks much clearer now.  Do you have any expectations or information about the correlations of the conditional responses?

Comment: @whuber, do you mean the independent variables (x1 and x2)? They measure different aspects of heart rate variability and show a high degree of temporal autocorrelation. Correlations between `x1` and `x2` are over 0.80 across all of the dependent variables (ys).

Comment: No: conditional responses are the "error terms" in the regressions.  The correlations of `x1` and `x2` slightly affect the issue of multiple testing but the correlations among the `y1` through `y4` can affect it too: they can help you determine whether you're looking at four closely related measures of the same response or independent responses.

Comment: @locus It has to do with the discrete nature of permutation tests (including all rank based tests, like the Mann-Whitney). With very small samples the lowest possible p-value may not be small (it may exceed any typical significance level). With $n_1=4, n_2=3$, there are $7\choose 3$ $=\frac{7\times 6\times 5}{3\times 2\times 1}= 35$ ways of arranging $7$ values into two samples of size $4$ & $3$. Hence you can't get a p-value below $\frac{2}{35}$. There's posts on site about this discreteness issue (especially on small samples), I'll see if I can dig one up.

Comment: I chose a small sample size deliberately but the lowest attainable significance level is a property of the two sample sizes, and the particular permutation test statistic, and the particular alternative under consideration (e.g. 1 vs 2 tailed). For permutation tests it's all a matter of counting possible rearrangements of data values into two samples of the same size as the original sample you have.